# Boostrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 model - how to center model title

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

How do you center a model's title?  I tired to add the class "text-center" to the h1 tag but it keeps showing the tile left aligned.

Thanks

Comment: Provide your code. so that we can go through and predict exact problem and give you proper answer.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the `w-100` class on the `h3.modal-title` element along with `text-center`.

```
<div class="modal-header text-center">
  <h3 class="modal-title w-100">Quiz Results</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! And I think it's better than using `.col-12` because `h3` is not inside a `.row`.

Answer (score 36):

I had to figure this out today in particular when I wanted a centered `modal-title` inside a `modal-header` - played around with a few different ways but here is what I settled on:

```
<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <h3 class='col-12 modal-title text-center'>
        Centered Modal Title
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key was having `col-12` if you want to do it inside of the 'modal-header' tag.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd been trying to get this for over an hour!

Comment: Baller. Way to go!

Answer (score 30):

> **The question has a detailed answer here**

[Bootstrap 4 Modal Center Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041065/bootstrap-4-modal-center-content)

Simply add *w-100* property value to class property. That is:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center">Contact us via Email</h5>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<h3 class="modal-title w-100 text-center">I'm centered title</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing modal-header

```
.modal-header{
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sava approach worked for me. Another way is to add  "margin: 0 auto;" for any css class you are using for a title. for example if you use modal-title, add to your css:

```
.modal-title {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add these classes to modal-header 
.ml-auto .mr-auto

```
<div class="modal-header ml-auto mr-auto">
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Model Title</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the title **and** maintain the *dismiss* button you could do something like this:

```
<div class="modal-header pl-0">
    <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center position-absolute">Title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes CSS is enough, even in bootstrap vue:

`<b-modal id="mymodal" title="My Modal">`

you just need:

```
.modal-title{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

in your css file to have it centered.

Answer (score 0):

try `style="margin: 0 auto;"` like `<h5 class="modal-title" style="margin: 0 auto;">title</h5>` it's work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `.justify-content-center` class in modal header div:

```
<div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
     //your content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 text-center"><h5 class="modal-title">Чтото пошло не так... :(</h5></div>
    <div class="col-1 ms-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" onclick="closeModal()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]