# Bootstrap 4 Modal Center Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can someone please explain how to horizontally center the title in a Bootstrap 4 modal.

I've tried `text-center`, `mx-auto` and `ml-0 / mr-0` but they don't appear to work.

Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/k21pnfnd/) to a fiddle.

Code below;

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try : <center><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5></center>

Comment: @alexay68 No no no, don't use the `center` tag.

Comment: @DavidG why not ? What's the problem with <center> tag ?

Comment: @alexay68 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @DavidG Oh damn I didn't know... time to search and replace it in all my projects x)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `modal-header` is display:flex so centering its' content (like the `modal-title`) works differently. You can use `mx-auto` but then centering is relative to the close button so it's not exactly centered.

One option is to make the header display:block (`d-block`) and use `text-center`.

https://jsfiddle.net/44v0b25k/

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header d-block">
        <button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to use `w-100` on the `modal-title` so that it's full width, and `text-center` will also work.

```
<div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/306ob2e5/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is perfect! :)

Answer (score 8):

Below I have added `text-center d-block` to the header and `d-inline-block` to the title.

The problem was that the header was flex with justify-content space-between which pushed your title to the left.

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center d-block">
        <h5 class="modal-title d-inline-block" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/oHLT6ciKZ6)

Answer (score 1):

Just apply CSS to the `modal-title` class, for example:

```
.modal-title {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxsw0xsy/