# Bootstrap4 Modal-title not fully centered

Tags: html, css

!Do not close it as duplicate, the answers in the "duplicate" only center it relative to the X button!

I'm trying to completely center the modal-title of a bootstrap4 modal.
However, it only centers it relative to the X and not to the whole width of the modal. The answers here: [Bootstrap 4 Modal Center Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041065/bootstrap-4-modal-center-content) all have the same issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/couthzLt/

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center d-block">
          <h5 class="modal-title d-inline-block" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The header is not completely centered as you can see on this image that:
[modal header centered relative to X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pb3X.png)

My question is if it's possible to center it to the right edge of the modal - not the X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `close` is positioned using `float:right` which keeps it as part of the document flow.  Because of this `modal-title` is always going to center itself respective of the width available *minus* what `close` is using.

To fix the problem we need to pull `close` out of the flow.  Easiest way to do that is:

```
.close { 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 1rem;
}
```

`position: absolute` pulls the class out of the normal flow which in turn lets `modal-title` take up the full width. The `right` margin is designed to replicate the margins defined for the Modal component to ensure that your layout remains more or less unchanged.

Comment: Or there is option B if you don't wanna use absolute position of `close` icon, you can set 
`.modal-title {
    margin-right: -49px;
}`
as a negative px value being the width of close icon.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Robert C. A very helpful answer and thank you for taking your time and giving a detailed description <3

Answer (score 3):

1. Put text-center d-block in modal-header
2. Put up button dismiss
3. Last modal title.

```
<div class="modal-header text-center d-block">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h2 class="modal-title">Title center</h2>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
#exampleModalLabel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I did the following:-

- NOTE: The size of my modal was default, it was not large or small.

> Then in Modal::begin I added titleOptions as below

```
Modal::begin([
  'title' => 'yor title ...',
  'titleOptions' => ['style' => ['margin-left' => '95px']],
  ...other options..
]);
```